# Saber o último schema que foi alterado synonym

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Tenho um servidor Oracle que possui diversos *schema*, para efeito de explicação, entenda a metáfora:

Existem *schema* classificados como LETRAS, e *schema* classificados como NUMÉRICOS, e varias vezes preciso alterar o sinônimos entre LETRAS e NÚMEROS.

> Todas as LETRAS podem tem *grants* de NÚMEROS, mas os NÚMEROS não, ou
>   seja, as LETRAS podem saber quais objetos tem nos NÚMEROS.

Exemplo: Os *schema* UM,DOIS,TRES tem `grants` para o *schema* A. Então crio um sinônimos privado no *schema* A:

```
 create or replace synonym TABELA1 for UM.TABELA1;
```

Dessa forma ao fazer uma query no schema A:

```
select * from tabela1;
```

Terei retorno dos dados da tabela1 do schema UM.

> **Problema:** Tenho um gerenciador de schemas, e preciso saber qual é o schema que foi feito a última alteração de sinônimos.

Tentei usar:

**user_objects:** Tem alguns dados de data e hora, mas não serve.
**user_tables:** Tem dados da hora da analise.
**USER_DEPENDENCIES:** nada
**ALL_SOURCE:** nada

Comment: TENTOU SELECT Last_Ddl_Time FROM USER_OBJECTS ?

Comment: @Motta, tentei sim, essa data é de quando foi criado, mesmo colocando `create or replace` essa data não é alterada se vc modifica o `synonym` somente ao criar, dessa forma não servindo para o meu proposito :/

Comment: na doc consta "LAST_DDL_TIME  DATE  NOT NULL  Timestamp for the last modification of the object resulting from a DDL statement (including grants and revokes)"